# Why is my iPhone playing the notification sound but no notification is showing?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

A few minutes ago I was listening to music on my iPhone and the music faded out and then the notification sound played but no notifcation showed. (it has done this about 10-15 times now) Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong with my iPhone? I have an iPhone 3GS running on iOS 5.0.1.

Sometimes it's an email sound but other times it's the actual notification sound. I have it set up to show the little notification at the top for new emails so it should show a notifcation even when the email sound plays. Most of the time it shows a notification but sometimes it doesn't.

Maybe this is just a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have the new Gmail app installed.  Every time it gets a new email, it triggers the "iphone Text Message sound".  The sound can be disabled via Settings app > Notifications > Gmail > uncheck Sound.

Comment: Yes, I have the Gmail app installed. So that's the problem. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there a way to turn this sound off? It is very annoying. I use the main Mail app but I like having the Gmail app too.

Comment: Go to Settings app > Gmail and disable the sound for notifications.  If this solves it, please mark my answer as Correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: There's no disable sound notifications. Look at this screen shot I took: http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/2418/photonov2430033am.png There's only 2 options. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say go to Settings app > Notifications > Gmail, then disable Sound.